# What did Robert California from "The Office" say to Nellie in his voice mail?

Tags: dialogue, the-office

So in Season 8 - Episode 23 "Turf War", Robert had a drunk night. He apparently sent an "inappropriate" voicemail to Nellie as she says:

> Nellie: I got your voicemail. From – from last night.
>   Robert:
>   Wonderful.
>   Nellie: And the answer… is yes, yes, yes, yes, and never.

... But Robert has no clue as to what he said, so he turns to Pam to find out.

> Robert: Apparently, I left a phone message for Nellie last night, and I need you to find out what I said.
>   Pam: Um, I am a little busy.
>   Robert: Yes, ‘course. Why don’t you list the things that would keep you from helping me.
>   Pam: Yeah, I can make you a list.
>   Robert: Let’s do it now. What’s number one?
>   Pam: Why don’t I help you now?
>   Robert: There we go.
>   Pam: Okay.

So Pam steals her phone and shows to Robert but as the messages were so disturbing, she deleted the voice messages and we never got to see what was the voicemail sent to Nellie.

Later, Nellie tells Pam about the voicemail and how it is wildly inappropriate:

> Pam: No. My goodness. You have a lot going on. With Robert and everything.
>   Nellie: Oh, god, Pam. Don’t get me started.
>   Pam: No, I will not.
>   Nellie: You’ve just got me started. Robert… is… a filthy beast. I mean, don’t you get the feeling, he’s just thinking of fifteen different ways to do you?
>   Pam: Well –
>   Nellie: I mean, the man talks of nothing but sex.
>   Pam: But sometimes he talks about flesh… and bacchanals.
>   Nellie: I cannot even tell you what he left on my phone last night.

What was it? How bad could it be? What does "yes, yes, yes, yes, and never" refer to?

Comment: He most likely proposed a number of outlandish sexual positions, and she replied yes to all except to the last one. We were never going to hear any of them (since they would be unbroadcastable), so instead you're supposed to use your imagination. The actual content isn't important, the funny is in the reactions etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB so.. Nellie should not be as disgusted as she seems, since she agreed to 80% of what Robert had to say. She basically liked what Robert said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We'll never know and it is likely the writers didn't even have anything specific in mind, but we can make some likely inferences.

**The last question was most likely a proposal that was sexual in nature.**

In discussions about the message, Nellie expresses contempt and disgust for Robert California on the basis of his sexual depravity, so we can infer that the final question--to which she answered "never"--was most likely a proposal that she engage in a depraved (in her opinion) sex act with Robert. Her disdain for the man naturally prompts an answer of "Never."

**The first four were likely personal questions.**

Since he disgusts her, but she answered "yes" to the first four questions, the four yeses that he received were probably not proposals, but rather questions about herself. Given that they likely led up to a sexual proposal, the questions probably dealt with her knowledge, experience, and preferences with regards to sex, but not specific to doing anything with Robert himself. Some examples might be:

- Do certain things arouse her, or does she have any unusual desires?
- Does she prefer any particular sexual acts or positions?
- Has she ever engaged in any specific or unusual sexual acts?
- Would she be willing to try a specific sexual act?

Or they could have been personal questions that are related less directly to actual sex acts, such as:

- Are you gay/straight/bi?
- Are you a natural redhead? (An old innuendo referring to pubic hair).
- Do you enjoy wine?
- Did you have a good time at my mansion?

To any of these questions Nellie might reasonably answer "yes" since they are not specific to doing anything with Robert himself. She may have answered "yes" to them truthfully, or untruthfully to get Robert's hopes up before dashing them with the "never."